# How to change the thumb icon of the material-ui slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I would like to set the custom icon for the slider like in the above image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AirbnbSlider` where you can set the `ThumbComponent` to change the icon.
https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#discrete-sliders

https://www.tutorialguruji.com/react-js/how-to-style-each-thumb-independently-when-material-ui-slider-have-multiple-thumbs/

```
function AirbnbThumbComponent(props) {
  return (
    <span {...props}>
      <span className="bar" />
      <span className="bar" />
      <span className="bar" />
    </span>
  );
}
...
...
<AirbnbSlider 
     ThumbComponent={AirbnbThumbComponent} 
     defaultValue={[20]} 
/>
```

Comment: did you succeed? Can you share example?

Comment: is there actually documentation on how to do this or do we just have a Codesandbox that shows it and that's it? I'd like to change other components of the slider as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change it with simple css using the class from the MUI documentation:

```
.MuiSlider-thumb {
  background-image: url("./Images/arrow.svg");
}
```